# How to combine attributes in Core Data using Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a basic app that allows a user to select from an array of animals: [Cat, Bird, Dog] and record number of times they see it throughout the day. I am using Core Data to save each user's session. When I fetch the results from Core Data they look something like:

Animal: Bird, Seen: 2

Animal: Cat, Seen: 1

Animal: Bird, Seen: 4

Sessions is the entity while the attributes are animal: String and seen: Int.

I then have a label for each animal with the total times seen. 
Example: Bird - Total: 6, Cat - Total: 1, Dog - Total 0

How can I add the attribute "seen" together for each of the animal attributes to produce a total amount for each one? The code below produces the fetched core data results.

```
 let context = coreDataStack.managedContext
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Sessions>(entityName: "Sessions")

   do {
                let tasks = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

                   for task in tasks {
                    print("Animal: \(task.animal)")
                    print("Seen: \(String(describing: seen))")
                   }
               } catch let error {
                   print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
               }
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of Sessions. Basically we need know what a `task` is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

according to your question, I guess every data entry will have:

1. animal name (String)
2. seen count (Int)

So, maybe you can try using a dictionary to hold the total count for each of your animals

```
var animalCount = [String : Int]()

for task in tasks {
    if animalCount[task.animal] == nil {
        animalCount[task.animal] = task.seen
            //I assume this seen is a property of this task
    } else {
        animalCount[task.animal] = animalCount[task.animal]! + task.seen
    }
}
animalCount.forEach{print("Animal: \($0.key) - Total: \($0.value)")}
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks! Yes, animal name is of type String and seen is of type Int.